# C# Program Crash comboBox SelectedItem ToString

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have no idea, why my program crash.

If i click "Reload" Button:

```
private void reloadBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    comboFilter.Items.Clear();
    dataGridPrivatecustomers.Columns.Clear();
    dataGridPrivatecustomers.ItemsSource = null;
    load_columns_privatecustomer();
    load_values_privatecustomer();
}
```

All works.
But if I select a filter for my search function and click reload, then it crashes:

```
private void comboFilter_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    labelfilter.Content = "Filter: " + comboFilter.SelectedItem;
    filtervalue = comboFilter.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

This is the breakpoint:

```
filtervalue = comboFilter.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

And I get a NulLReferenceException Error.
I tryed to make a `filtervalue = null;` in reloadBtn_Click but also doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried surrounding your code with a try catch clause to get more information about your error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `comboFilter_SelectionChanged` is somehow fired after the reload where you remove items from the `combo`, which is result of clear method. Make sure you have `SelectedItem` not null in `comboFilter_SelectionChanged` before you use it.

```
private void comboFilter_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if( comboFilter.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        labelfilter.Content = "Filter: " + comboFilter.SelectedItem;
        filtervalue = comboFilter.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
}
```

As a additional note your program must not crash by not catching the exception being thrown in your program. Use [try-catch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx) to properly handle the exception. And also try to avoid them before they could occur. Like we did here by checking for null. This will prevent program crashing.

[try-catch (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx) - Why program would crash (stop execution)

> When an exception is thrown, the common language runtime (CLR) looks
>   for the catch statement that handles this exception. If the currently
>   executing method does not contain such a catch block, the CLR looks at
>   the method that called the current method, and so on up the call
>   stack. If no catch block is found, then the CLR displays an unhandled
>   exception message to the user and stops execution of the program.

Comment: Thx for the answer. It works now. Im new to C# so sorry ^^

Comment: You are welcome @OJean, no problem. It is part of learning process.

Answer (score 1):

The exception gets thrown because `comboFilter_SelectionChanged` is called implicitly from `reloadBtn_Click` when `comboFilter.Items.Clear()` is called. In this case `comboFilter.SelectedItem` changes from the previously selected item to `null`.

Check for `null` in `comboFilter_SelectionChanged`:

```
private void comboFilter_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (comboFilter.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        labelfilter.Content = "Filter: " + comboFilter.SelectedItem;
        filtervalue = comboFilter.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add a null-check for comboFilter.SelectedItem, e.g. like comboFilter.SelectedItem?.ToString()